# Use Xpath and IMPORTXML to check for the presence of a word in the content of a URL

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I am not English, please excuse me in advance for my level. I'm trying to be able to verify the presence of a word (example: "swimming") in the content of a URL. I would like the result to be true or false, I searched for several hours but failed .. if anyone had a lead .. thanks in advance!

I test this but this don't work :/

//text() = 'swimming'

Comment: Hi there @PoppYN! I don't understand where you want to look for matches. Could you please show a content example?

Comment: Hi, I would like to have a set of words in a first column and check for a given URL if all the lexical field is present in the page. For a page about the car, I would like to have "true" or "false" on the word car, wheel, engine, etc. Thx in advance :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question. I don't get what you mean by «*the content of a URL*». Do you mean the URL string or the webpage insides? Also please share the methods/resources that you used, so we all can offer you a hand.